# How to find ZCTA for the 2010 Census block code?

Tags: data, united-states, census, block

I'm trying to find ZIP Code Tabulation Areas for the list of 2010 Census block codes.

How to get ZIP Code Tabulation Areas for Census block code?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  The tour states there should be just one question per Question, however here you have asked several.  Please [edit] your question to focused on a single specific question.  This also looks like it may be off-topic as there doesn't appear to be any GIS component to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used ZCTAs before but in reading the [Census Bureau description](https://www.census.gov/geo/reference/gtc/gtc_bg.html) it appears that they may not match block groups completely.  Having said that, there does not appear to be an attribute for a ZCTA in the block group level data within those available from American FactFinder.

One potential solution could be to perform a spatial join with the TigerLine geographies that are matched with the FactFinder data.  If you are using ArcGIS your could look here for guidance: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/spatial-join.htm

Comment: You are right regarding block groups but as I've read the block codes (15 figures) should belong to ZCTA. Actually I need ZIP-to-block code correspondence table but ZCTA is ok as well. Does ArcMap allows to realize this solution?

Answer (score 1):

This example uses ArcGIS Desktop 10.4 with shapefiles downloaded from TigerLine.  Blocks are for Denver County, CO and the ZCTA file is for the entire state.  In this case a spatial join was performed with these parameters:

[image]

This produced the table found [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AS8gyeSW8gQOtXoYiWPTGfc7dzXMH_Qc7bui4qhhWeA/pubhtml) which is the dbf file for the shapefile.  This may be opened as a spreadsheet.  The attribute "GEOID 10" is the 15 figure code for the block while "ZCTA CE10" is the corresponding ZCTA code in which that block exists.

Does that table suffice?

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to make the test. I have few questions? Did you use ArcMap (this is the only one I happened to install)? If Did you use tl_2010_08_county10 as county data?

Comment: I'm away from my laptop right now.  I'll confirm the file name in about an hour but I believe that is correct.  I used ArcMap 10.4.  ArcGIS Pro would be able to do this as well but the process is different.

Comment: Actually that is incorrect.  I used the file "tl_2010_08031_tabblock10" as the basis for my join and joined features as shown above from "tl_2010_08_zcta510".  The file you are referring to is geography for counties, not blocks.  You can find the block shapefile in the same area but you need to select blocks from the pull-down if you are using the web interface.

Comment: I've loaded both shapefiles and imported them with "Add data" menu. Then I clicked on 'tl_2010_08031_tabblock10' and selected these menus: 'Join and Relates' -> 'Join'. Then I've tried to choose the result file but the only working option for 'Save as type' was 'shapefile'. When I've tried to save it as 'Database feature classes' I got an error: 'An error occured trying to save object named "Join_Output"'. I also tried to save the result as shape file and then to make 'Export Data' as 'Database feature classes' but the same problem appears.

Comment: You don't need to export to dbf.  After you complete the join and view the attribute table to make sure the join worked you will export the joined file to a new shapefile.  The dbf is one of several files included in what is referred to as a shapefile.  If you use your file explorer in Windows to navigate to the location where you exported the newly joined layer you will see several files with the name of the shapefile followed by a unique extension.  In Excel or some other spreadsheet software open the file with the ".dbf" extension at that location.  That should be the table you want.

Comment: Sorry. I was wrong, dbf file was saved together with shp. I suppose I got the same file as yours (my has 11040 records). But I can't find ZCTA there (in my and yours file). Please, advise.

Comment: Check your attribute tables for the original ZCTA file you downloaded from TigerLine and the newly joined file.  You should be able to figure out the association between them.  I believe your ZCTA code should be under the attribute "GEOID 10" but I may be remembering​ that incorrectly.  I'm away from my laptop for the rest of the day so play around with those tables.  If you cannot find it, zip that new shapefile and post it here.

Comment: Success :) Thank you. BTW There is data for later periods (upto 2016). Did you try to use it? It looks like the format is different then in 2010.

Comment: I'm glad it worked.  Yes, there is more recent data from the American Fact Finder website.  There are some limitations you should be aware of though.  The 2010 data are from the decennial census so they are from the measure of the full US population.  The data from other years are from the American Community Survey.  Only the five year rolling survey covers all places regardless of size.  Additionally, as the geographies get smaller (as in the case of blocks), the margin of error increases as this is a sample of the population.  Neither of these are of concern with the 2010 data.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it sounds like you found a reasonable work-around for your issue.

I know that the LEHD contains crosswalk information on many different levels of geography relating to a Census 2010 Block. The [documentation](https://lehd.ces.census.gov/data/lodes/LODES7/LODESTechDoc7.2.pdf#page=11) explains the layout of the data, which are located by state in this [ftp repository](https://lehd.ces.census.gov/data/lodes/LODES7/).